# I want to default checked one radio button first. After then when I back I want to check radio button which was value selected from database Angular 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular2-forms

How default radio button checked first. Previous button clicked then previous selected value radio button checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="Answer" [(ngModel)]="Answer" [value]="Test[i].ans1" (change)="selected(Test[i].ans1)"  formControlName="Answer"> :{{Test[i].ans1}}<br />
<input type="radio" name="Answer" [(ngModel)]="Answer" [value]="Test[i].ans2" (change)="selected(Test[i].ans2)"  formControlName="Answer"> :{{Test[i].ans2}}<br />
<input type="radio" name="Answer" [(ngModel)]="Answer" [value]="Test[i].ans3" (change)="selected(Test[i].ans3)" formControlName="Answer"> :{{Test[i].ans3}} <br />
<input type="radio" name="Answer" [(ngModel)]="Answer" [value]="Test[i].ans4" (change)="selected(Test[i].ans4)" formControlName="Answer"> :{{Test[i].ans4}}<br />
</div>
<button (click)="Prevoius($event)" class="btn btn-primary">Previous</button>
<button type="button" [disabled]="radioTest.controls['Answer'].invalid" (click)="Next($event)" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<input type="radio" name="Answer" [(ngModel)]="Answer" [value]="Test[i].ans1" (change)="selected(Test[i].ans1)" [checked] =“!Answer”  formControlName="Answer"> :{{Test[i].ans1}}<br />
```

by using [checked] you can make checkbox checked

Comment: Nice. but how can i Cheked radio  button selected value  when i back button presss

Comment: Do one thing [checked] =“ Test[i].ans1  == Answer” like this for all checkbox

Comment: Do one thing [checked] =“!Answer ? true : Test[i].ans1  == Answer” like this for all checkbox , [checked] =“ Test[i].ans2  == Answer”

Comment: It is nice but my problem is that when i press back button then it is ok to selected previous value. After that i select next vvalue up to end Then my slected value is only first selected vlue for all.  Means there is no catch not clear so without selection it take that value. How to solve it please.....

Comment: How to clear catch of radio button

Comment: <input type="radio" name="Answer" [(ngModel)]="Answer" [value]="Test[i].ans1" (change)="selected(Test[i].ans1)"  formControlName="Answer" [checked] ="Test[i].ans1 == Answer"> :{{Test[i].ans1}}<br />
           <input type="radio" name="Answer" [(ngModel)]="Answer" [value]="Test[i].ans2" (change)="selected(Test[i].ans2)"  formControlName="Answer" [checked] ="Test[i].ans2 == Answer"> :{{Test[i].ans2}}<br />